# Ubuntu upgrade problems

Tags: upgrade

I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04.

I faced a problem when my Internet connection disconnected while the files were downloading.

Now, I can download all the 600+MB packages again, but I have the already downloaded files stored in `/tmp` can I restart the download from where it stopped?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you retry to upgrade, it will start at the point where your connection broke off and will not download all the 600mb data.

By the way how did you download the 600mb packages, using apt-get upgrade?

Comment: I did the upgrade via the UI, did not use the command line. What seemed to happen when i tried using the UI- it started all over again..

Comment: well i think the GUI is a front end for the command line, so it should also pick up where it left off...dont know why thats not happening.